# alphabet validation on textbox in javascript using event keypress

Tags: javascript, html, validation, textbox

I am trying to validate the form when any special characters or number press in the text box it should trigger an error as alert.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function demoMatchClick() {

  var reg = new RegExp("[a-z]|[A-Z]");
  if (document.form.name.value.match(reg)) {
    alert("Successful match");

  } else {
    alert("Not a match");

  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
    <form onSubmit="alert('submit')" name="form">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name" onkeyup="demoMatchClick();"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with This:

```js
function demoMatchClick(inputtxt) {
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var val = inputtxt.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
  if (val.match(letters)) {
    alert("Successful match");

  } else {
    alert("Not a match");

  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body >
    <form onSubmit="alert('submit')" name="form">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name" onkeyup="demoMatchClick(this);"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'd be extremely annoyed if an alert box popped up just because my finger slipped.

Comment: Even so, you should not prevent the user from typing what they want. Because if I slip, I will hit Backspace, and then there's a missing character of valid input.

Comment: Could you please let me konw the regex format for entering only numbers for phone number field

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Letters only!"/>
```

Done. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/95d94qkf/)

Comment: @ Niet the Dar Absol your suggestion is good but he wants validation on onKeyPress event.